# Power apps gallery

Tags: powerapps-canvas

each gallery has few status columns.
I want count all status that say "FREE" within each row. Status columns are text boxes.

Using formula below, which does not give any errow, however is not returning desired value.

CountIf(Split(Concatenate(ThisItem.Status,",", ThisItem.Status_2,",", ThisItem.Status_3,","),","), Text="FREE")

any ideas?

[image: List & app snapshot]

Comment: Can you show us the data structure (maybe with example values) or screenshot of gallery & example of expected/desired output? It is unclear from the question what exactly you want.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, I have edit question by adding a list and app snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula, to count the values based on different columns in a single row.

```
With({
    status1: If(ThisItem.Status = "Free", 1, 0),
    status2: If(ThisItem.Status_2 = "Free", 1, 0),
    status3: If(ThisItem.Status_3 = "Free", 1, 0)
}, Sum(status1, status2, status3))
```

I hope, this solves your problem.